# Paypal sandbox accounts gives "This payment attempt is already processed" error

Tags: php, paypal

I have been using the PayPal sandbox accounts to test checkout procedures from my e-commerce site. It has been working perfect up to today. For some reason each time I try a transaction and the page is redirected to the sandbox account, once I click Pay Now I get the message "This payment attempt is already processed". Once this occurs PayPal (obviously) does not redirect me back to my site! What has changed on the PayPal site since yesterday? I am using simple Checkout buttons from PayPal. I also noticed that the Sandbox account home page has changed and it is a bit harder now to find where the appropriate account settings are. So my question is primarily to find out if anyone else had the same issue that can shed some light on this. Thanks!

This is the form that sends the cart items to PayPal - this has been working for the past few months without an issue:

```
<form target="_self" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx-seller@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<?php       
$customerCart = array();                        
$customerid = $_SESSION['customerid'];
$customerCart = getCartArray($customerid);
$idx_row = 1;

foreach ($customerCart as $elems1) {

?>

<!-- we start from idx=1 as Paypal requests -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $idx_row?>" value="<?php echo $elems1['Item_name']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_<?php echo $idx_row?>" value="<?php echo $elems1['Quantity']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $idx_row?>" value="<?php echo $elems1['Price']; ?>">

<?php

$idx_row++;

}
?>

<br><strong>Checkout & Pay:</strong>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<br>

</form>
```

Comment: So.... Hi there, how about some code that the folks here can pick through to see where things are going wrong?

Comment: Absolutely - I didn't post the code since it is the same form that has been working all along but you are right may be something needs to be tweaked. I will post the form that sends the data to PayPal next.

Comment: The issue persists - switching browsers helped for one transaction but then again on subsequent transactions the same issue occurs. The PayPal site complains that this transaction has been processed already and I can actually see it in the seller site but it won't continue to return to the user site! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem this morning, then noticed a few issues with the live payments. Everything seems to be working fine for me again though. I did clear all my cache and cookies, just to be sure. That might help, but I suspect this was a PayPal issue.